# How to access subcomponentes in QML

Tags: qt, qml

I want to create my custom combo box. So I went and desinged a simple item that is a rectancle with a mouse area and a text. My idea is to draw multiple of these according to the values in an string array. Here is my code so far for the item:

```
Item {

    signal itemSelected(int id);

    property int vmItemIndex: 0;
    property alias itemBody: ibody;

    Rectangle{

        id: ibody;
        property alias itemMouseArea: imouseArea;
        property alias itemText: itext;

        Text{
            id: itext
            anchors.centerIn: parent
        }

        MouseArea {
            id: imouseArea
            anchors.fill: parent
            onClicked: itemSelected(vmItemIndex);
        }

    }




}
```

the acutual combo box

```
Item {

    property int vmWidth: 300;
    property int vmHeight: 50;
    property int vmCurrentIndex: 0;
    property var vmItemTexts: ["Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3"];
    property string vmBackColor: "#ff0000";

    VMComboBoxItem {
        id: main;
        itemBody.itemText.text: vmItemTexts[vmCurrentIndex];
        itemBody.width: vmWidth
        itemBody.height: vmHeight
        itemBody.color: vmBackColor
    }

}
```

Hoewever the engine load fails telling me it cannot access itemText. So what am I doing wrong?

Comment: assuming that the first part of code is `VMComboBoxItem.qml` it has no property `itemText`.

Comment: I don't understand. It says property alias itemText: itext. How is it that it has not property item text?

Comment: `itemText` is now visible outside the item. If you want to expose it out you should create alias property

Comment: @folibis: No,  `itemBody` is exposed which has `itemText` - and that is how `itemText` is accessed. It should work. But there seems to be a problem with the `alias` - I would assume it is a bug maybe with type resolution or order of access... I don't know. Since, when you draw the `itemBody` into a seperate file, it suddenly works.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that in your `VMComboBoxItem` component, you expose the inner `Rectangle` as a property. There's some [hint about this in the Qt documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-syntax-objectattributes.html#considerations-for-property-aliases).

What you can do instead is to expose selected properties directly in your "root" item in `VMComboBoxItem`:

```
import QtQuick 2.0

Item {

    signal itemSelected(int id);

    property int vmItemIndex: 0;
    property alias itemBody: ibody;

    // Expose the "text" property directly:
    property alias text: itext.text

    Rectangle{

        id: ibody;
        property alias itemMouseArea: imouseArea;
        property alias itemText: itext;

        Text{
            id: itext
            anchors.centerIn: parent
        }

        MouseArea {
            id: imouseArea
            anchors.fill: parent
            onClicked: itemSelected(vmItemIndex);
        }
    }
}
```

And then set this property in QML code using your component:

```
import QtQuick 2.0

Item {

    property int vmWidth: 300;
    property int vmHeight: 50;
    property int vmCurrentIndex: 0;
    property var vmItemTexts: ["Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3"];
    property string vmBackColor: "#ff0000";

    VMComboBoxItem {
        id: main;
        itemBody.width: vmWidth
        itemBody.height: vmHeight
        itemBody.color: vmBackColor

        // Set Text property directly:
        text: vmItemTexts[vmCurrentIndex];
    }    
}
```

It might generally be a good idea to expose only selected properties in your components, as this narrows the interface your component exposes (which in turn makes it much easier should you ever need to refactor your code).